# Closure: option to require var before new JS variables

Tags: javascript, jslint, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

How do you tell the Google Closure Compiler / Closure Linter to require "var" before new variables? Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) and tell to Google Closure to not ignore it by using:

`--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT`

The `language` parameter refers to which version of ECMAScript to assume when checking for errors in your code.

Setting language to `ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT` is like ECMASCRIPT5 but assumes compliance with strict mode (`"use strict";`).

Reference: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref

Comment: Hmm, any way other than using strict? Just want to require this one particular style.

Comment: @user3179047 : Don't know if it will work but you can try to set `warning_level` to `VERBOSE`. Keep in mind that the warning_level parameter only has an effect when an `output_info` parameter with a value of warnings is also supplied.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default for the command line compiler.  You need to use the --third_party flag, to cause it to assume the variables are defined.